# What is the syntax for declaring array of given type, as the value of a defined key in an Object, in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add a property to our `state` object, in vuex. This property is an array, which has objects pushed into it later.

**store.ts**

```
  state: {
    spudIsAnimating: false,
    selectedColor: colors[0],
    addedElements: object[] = [],
  },
  addToElements(state, element: object){
    state.addedElements.push(element);
  },
```

This gives error `[ts] Cannot find name 'object'. Did you mean 'Object'? [2552]`, and `[ts] Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`,

**store.ts**

```
addedElements: Object[] = [],
```

This gives the `argument of type...` error, as well as the new error `ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ObjectConstructor' has no index signature. [7017].`

**store.ts**

```
addedElements: Object[],
```

This fixes the `argument of type...` error, but the `index signature` error remains.

**store.ts**

```
addedElements: Array<Object>,
```

This gives error `[ts] Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'ArrayConstructor' and 'ObjectConstructor'.` Also, the `addToElement` function now has this error: `ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type 'boolean'. [2339]`.

I'm just trying to follow the syntax guidelines from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html):

> TypeScript, like JavaScript, allows you to work with arrays of values. Array types can be written in one of two ways. In the first, you use the type of the elements followed by [] to denote an array of that element type:

```
let list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

> The second way uses a generic array type, Array:

```
let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Nowhere in the documentation can I find instructions on "declaring array values within an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `addedElements: Array<any>` or it's equaliant `addedElements: any[]`

(First syntax is preferred due to TsLint)

Comment: Second syntax is cleaner in my opinion, it conveys the same information, and is more succinct and intuitive due to the brackets

Comment: However first one is `TsLint` friendly

Comment: It depends on how you configure your rules, but I agree that this is just a preference thing. Rule: array-type supports both notations